# USB barcode scanner and kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I'm trying to capture a barcode scan. Just for example, in Tkinter, I was able to do this like this:

The Label:

```
self.code = ' '         
self.status = tk.Label(frameStatus, text="Scanner is waiting...")
self.status.config(height=20, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

self.bind('<Key>', self.get_key)
```

The function:

```
def get_key(self, event):
    if event.char in '0123456789':
        self.code += event.char             
        self.status['text'] = "Searching UPC Code: " + self.code     

    elif self.status == self.status:
        self.animate()
        self.status.after(2000)         
        self.status['text'] = "Scanner is Waiting..."
        self.get_info()
        self.code = ' '
```

Now in Kivy, I have code in the `class MsgAppApp(App):` that binds to the label I will be changing:

```
class MsgAppApp(App):       

    def build(self):
        self.main_screen = MsgApp()
        return self.main_screen

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.main_screen.update_date, 1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.main_screen.update_time, 1)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard = self.main_screen.item_added)
```

The line:

```
Window.bind(on_keyboard = self.main_screen.item_added)
```

refers to a function called `item_added` that will do the label changing, but the problem is that when I scan, I'm only getting the `scancode` only. Not the actual numbers from the barcode. Really no problem because I could make a dictionary to interchange those numbers to the actual numbers. For example, the code number "48" refers to the number "0", code "49" to "1", so on... The biggest problem is that I'm only getting the last `scancode`. Here's my function:

```
def item_added(self, instance, scancode, *largs):
   scancodes = [ ]
   scancodes.append(scancode)
   print(scancodes)
```

I'm just printing to the terminal as of now. I get a line of codes in the terminal like:

```
48
55
56
55
52
50
50
51
48
49
57
49
13
```

By-the-way, 13 (at the end) pops up all the time. There is only 12 digits in most barcodes. If I stored that in a variable, that would be the number in the variable, 13. It's like the variable is not holding all the digits. I've tried a `for` loop but unable to store these `scancodes` in a variable or more appropriately, in a list. It's like 90% there, but not understanding how to get these codes stored in the list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) Create an empty list e.g. scancodes = [] (2) Append scan code to it e.g. scancodes.append(scancode).

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result. Now I have a list with [13] only. It's like it is "rushing" in, the digits, and the last one is only one preserved. Matter-of-fact, I've already tried that previously, just forgot to mention it.

Comment: Also, I interchanged "scancode" with "instance" and I get this 13 times,[<kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7f9e5627e670>] The same line.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the code how you append to the `list`. It seems you clear your `list` before every `append`?

Comment: I just edited my question, but whatever it is, it will only allow one scancode only, not multiple scancode(s). Whatever the last number that gets scanned is the last one appended. Which in this case, is [13]. I'm not using this correctly, obviously, but it's good for one input only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting "scancodes = []" in your method, the list will created and destroyed each time your method, item_added is called.

Use Kivy ListProperty as follow:

## Snippet

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
...
class MsgApp(...):
    scancodes = ListProperty([])    # creates an empty list
    ....
    def item_added(self, instance, scancode, *largs):
       self.scancodes.append(scancode)
       print(self.scancodes)
```

Comment: Thank you ikolim. The only thing I had to do different was print(self.scancodes). Now I have all the numbers in the list. The missing main component was the ListProperty. Thanks for helping me learn.